# Is there a better way to transfer funds from one card payment to multiple accounts than keeping my account balance topped up?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a marketplace app. I want buyers to be able to add items to their cart from multiple sellers, make a single card payment, and then this money to reach the respective seller's accounts.

Based on my current understanding, the best way to do this is here

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// Create a PaymentIntent:
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({ amount: 10000, currency: 'gbp', transfer_group: '{ORDER10}', });


// Create a Transfer to the connected account (later):
const transfer = await stripe.transfers.create({ amount: 7000, currency: 'gbp', destination: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}', transfer_group: '{ORDER10}', });


// Create a second Transfer to another connected account (later):
const secondTransfer = await stripe.transfers.create({ amount: 2000, currency: 'gbp', destination: '{{OTHER_CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}', transfer_group: '{ORDER10}', });
```

My issue with this is that it looks like I need to change payout settings to Manual from Automatic. And, I also need to manually keep the account balance topped up with my own money in anticipation of a user purchase.

Is there a way for the card payment send money to the account balance, and then for the transfer to go to the relevant account destinations.

Please let me know if I am misunderstanding something.

**Updated Code:**

```
 const { client_secret } = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 10000,
      currency: 'usd',
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
    });

const charges = await stripe.charges.list({
    payment_intent: paymentIntentId,
  });
  const charge = charges.data[0];

await stripe.transfers.create({
      amount: 4000,
      currency: 'usd',
      destination: "example1",
      source_transaction: charge.id,
    });

await stripe.transfers.create({
          amount: 4000,
          currency: 'usd',
          destination: "example2",
          source_transaction: charge.id,
        });
```

**I am expecting the application_fee sent to my bank account to be the remaining 2000.**

Comment: Card payment will take some time to become available in your account balance. It may be why you need to top up since the funds from the card payment are not available yet. If you do not wish to handle the transfer/fund availability on your own, you may consider including `source_transaction` param to let Stripe handle the [transfer availability](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-availability) for you.

Comment: Can you check my updated code at the bottom to see it makes sense?

Comment: Although I'm not too sure where you get `paymentIntentId` for Charge list retrieval according to your code, the basic logic is correct. [PaymentIntent ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-id) should be returned as `id` from the response of `stripe.paymentIntents.create`. Alternatively, you can use PaymentIntent retrieval with the [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status#identifying-charges) here to retrieve the latest Charge ID.

Comment: This worked for me, althoug I am now getting the following error:

`The currency of source_transaction's balance transaction (gbp) must be the same as the transfer currency (usd site:stackoverflow.com`

I plan on making a new question for this problem. Can you post your original response as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Great to hear that it's working. Re-post the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Card payment will take some time to become available in your account balance. It may be why you need to top up since the funds from the card payment are not available yet. If you do not wish to handle the transfer/fund availability on your own, you may consider including source_transaction param to let Stripe handle the [transfer availability](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-availability) for you.